# How to get OpenID authentication on SharePoint Services?

Tags: sharepoint, openid, wss-3.0

Is this even possible? I want to build a small community site but do not want to use Live ID.

Answer (score 1):

Sharepoint has an extensible authentication provider model, so you could use that to extend it to support openid.

Comment: ASP.NET 2.0 Provider Model: Introduction to the Provider Model 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479030.aspx

Answer (score 1):

See the [OpenID membership provider](http://openidmembership.codeplex.com/) project on CodePlex. This provides OpenID support for SharePoint.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking for a windows-based community site framework, I'd suggest Community Server, which has a free license and built-in OpenID support.

http://communityserver.com/products/express/

Answer (score 0):

Many people have already done this using DotNetOpenId with SharePoint.

There are [some discussions on the dotnetopenid mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/dotnetopenid/search?group=dotnetopenid&q=sharepoint&qt_g=Search+this+group) that cover this topic.  Feel free to post your question there to get the responses of a few people there who have done it.

Answer (score 0):

There are exists two solution that exactly meet your requirments:
SharePoint Claims Provider for SharePoint Claims Based Authentication that use Windows Live ID and other OpenID provider such as Google and yahoo.
it will allows you and your members sign in to your SharePoint site with any OpenID provider or Windows Live ID.

Check SharePoint Live Authentication here : http://www.shetabtech.com/english/SharePointLiveAuth